# How to Strip Python Output

Tags: python, linux, linux-distro

I want to strip `platform.linux_distribution()`.

Output is tuple `('Ubuntu', '11.10', 'oneiric')` but I want to show it as `"Ubuntu 11.10 oneriric"`

`.group(1)` is not working.

Comment: Not clear on the question. Are you trying to just format a tuple into a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`" ".join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.linux_distribution()
('Ubuntu', '11.04', 'natty')
>>> " ".join(platform.linux_distribution())
'Ubuntu 11.04 natty'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
" ".join(platform.linux_distribution())
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
' '.join(platform.linux_distribution())
```

I'm on a mac, so I don't have `platform.linux_distribution()`, but it looks like it should return an array.